# changing the password of root remote host with no interaction

Tags: ssh, openwrt, passwd

How could I change the password for a root account on remote server without a need to enter the password each time?

Localhost is a MacOS computer and I have sshpass installed, remote host in an openwrt based router - I cannot add any additional software there, so I cannot use expect tool for this case. I'd just like to run a script which will change a password.

Please advise

Comment: `chpasswd` would seem to be able to do what you want, read the man page.

Basically it take stdin of `user_name:password` and updates as required.

So `echo user:newpass | chpasswd` will work. Whether it is available on the required systems, is another problem.

Comment: The `expect` tool (`man expect`) requires nothing to be installed on the router. It runs only on the local host. Could you use `ssh` instead?